# Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I want to use the Bootstrap gem ruby code but after i added the gem file and bundle install, it keeps failing to install `ffi` and due to this error even after i have `.scss` file extension. the error code is below.

```
An error occurred while installing `ffi (1.15.5)`, and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  bootstrap was resolved to 5.3.0.alpha3, which depends on
    sassc-rails was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      sassc was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
        ffi
```

Smoothly install Bootstrap so i can quickly work on my project.

Comment: Copy paste full error please.